# Count occurrences of a pattern in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
a= ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar", "BAD," "baz"]
```

as you can see, there is a repeating pattern in the array:

```
"foo", "bar", "baz"
```

until the last pattern where it has in the pattern "BAD".

I want a method to find the last occurrence of the pattern '"foo", "bar", "baz"' as i am only interested in the *last* elements that don't follow the pattern.

what i would expect to return is something like this

```
array_after_some_method(a) => ["foo", "bar", "BAD", "baz"]
```

My thought process is to do something like this:

1. turn array into string
2. split at the pattern
3. count the number of occurrences of `"bar"`

However, this process seems pretty hacky. Is there a  smart way to do this?

Comment: What is **a pattern**? Is it defined by men or resolved by the program itself? Is `"baz"` itself a pattern? If not, why `["foo", "bar", "bar", "baz"]` is?

Comment: Your question is not clear, it but seems potentially interesting. You need to clarify with an edit, else you can expect more down votes and then closure. It's best to give a complete and unambiguous statement of the question in words, but if you find that difficult at least give some examples. Make the examples as short as possible, show your desired result (a number, string, array, hash, printed values, etc.) and assign a variable to each input object (as you have done with `a = ["foo"...`), so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: thanks cary--- i'm going to edit now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to revise your question a bit; I found the wording to be a bit confusing.

However, I *think* you're looking for something like this:

```
array = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "baz"]

def useful_method(array, str)
  array.select { |member| 
    member == str
  }.length
end

useful_method array, 'bar' # => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the repeating pattern as starting with 'foo' this would work:

```
a.slice_before(a.first).map { |ary| ary }.last
```

However, if there are multiple `'foo'`s in the pattern, this will only get the last one. To capture the whole pattern, you could try this:

```
def last_pattern(arr)
  arr
    .chunk { |x| x }                           # group by value
    .slice_before { |x| x.first == arr.first } # find pattern based on first element in arr
    .to_a                                      # turn enumerator into Array
    .last                                      # take only the last pattern
    .flat_map(&:last)                          # join the chunked elements back
end

last_pattern(a)
# => ["foo", "bar", "bar", "bad"]
```

Then just use `Enumerable#count` to count for a specific element:

```
last_pattern(a).count { |x| x == 'bar' }
# => 2
```

Or even count them all using Enumerable#group_by:

```
Hash[last_pattern(a).group_by { |x| x }.map { |k, v| [k, v.length] }]
# => {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2, "baz"=>1}
```

Comment: That is *a lot* of method calls. What's the deal with `map {|x, y| [x, y] }` and `map {|x| x }`? Those are no-ops.

Comment: Good point - vestiges of earlier attempts. The ```.map { |x| x }``` is the same as ```.to_a```. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

im a new ruby hobyist myself and am learning methods in ruby now. I do have basic programming knowledge from knowing c++ and bits of other languages. what i think you can do is find length of your array possibly with .length method (or function) in ruby. then use a for loop and go through each index:

if this was your array declaration:

```
array = ["foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar"]
```

then your for loop will look like this:

```
for array [, variable ...] in expression [do]
   if (variable = array[index#])
    count++; //count is used to increment the count token to keep track of the occurences of "bar", or "foo" and other array elements
   end
end
```

the exact Ruby syntax might not be accurate though.

Comment: sergio thanks for the edit,
i wasn't sure how to do that